# UPDATE table vs JOIN performance

Tags: query-performance, join, update, ssrs

I currently have a query with roughly 10 JOIN statements that takes about 10 seconds to run.  I have this displayed as a report on SSRS.

Would it be better to create a table in SQL server and run UPDATE on all the columns to improve the speed of when the report loads?  There is roughly 15 columns of data.  Or is this a waste of time and would not make the query faster?  If so how to make it faster?

Comment: Impossible to answer without table definitions, query and plans etc.  Not even sure what you mean by "run UPDATE...".  I suggest you edit the Q to include all this & more detail.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: By UPDATE I mean like create a table with the query data in sql server then running some sort of update statement on the table to refresh the data with latest.  Right now it's just running a big query.

Answer (score 0):

> I currently have a query with roughly 10 JOIN statements that takes about 10 seconds to run. I have this displayed as a report on SSRS.
>
> Would it be better to create a table in SQL server and run UPDATE on all the columns to improve the speed of when the report loads?

10 `JOIN` statements = 10 `JOIN` statements. It doesn't matter much if they're `SELECT`ed against or used in an `UPDATE` statement, the same amount of work needs to be done to process those `JOIN`s. They will likely have the same (or very similar) query plans to serve those 10 `JOIN`s.

However, if your report runs more frequently than when the data would need to be updated, then caching the results of the 10 `JOIN` statements to a single table would likely be a net gain in performance. Having the report read from a single table will be faster than reading from the query with 10 `JOIN`s in it. It would also reduce resource contention on your server, since the 10 `JOIN`s would be running less frequently.

The catch is you have to ensure you handle concurrency properly, should someone attempt to run the report at the same time that the data in the cached table was being updated. One graceful way to handle that is with [optimistic concurrency isolation levels](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/), such as Read Committed Snapshot Isolation or Snapshot Isolation. The short story of how they work, is that when DML changes occur on a table, the previous version of the data is kept available to queries that need to read that data, up until the changes to that table are committed and available.

---

Outside of that, improving the runtime of the query with 10 `JOIN`s itself is not possible to comment on without the information requested by LoztInSpace. But as mentioned above, if caching the results of the query to a table reduces the number of times that query is ran, then obviously running it less often is a better overall outcome anyway.